# execute less with execv?

Tags: c, unix, exec, pipe

I have the following c code. I want to display my file with less by calling `execv()`
however the following seems never work. The program terminates and noting pop out.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void){
  int pid; 
  if(pid=fork()>0){
      //read in from stdin and pass to pipe
   }else if(pid==0){
      //read from pipe
      //write to out.txt
      //everything up to here works fine

      char* para[]={"less","/Desktop/out.txt"};
      execv("/bin/less",para);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: This will most likely be closed because of lack of effort... Just as a pointer, though - `=` is assignment, `==` is equality; you might want to review your code.

Comment: sorry, In my c file it is pid=fork()>0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(The original code contained `execv("bin/less", para);`.) Unless the current directory is the root directory, `/`, or unless there is a program `less` in the subdirectory `./bin/less`, then one of your problems is that you have a probable typo in the name of the executable.  That assumes the program is `/bin/less` and not `/usr/bin/less`.  You might even use `execvp()` to do a PATH-based search for the program.

There's an additional problem: you need to include a null pointer to mark the end of the argument list.

Finally, you can print an error message after the `execv()` returns.  The mere fact that it returns tells you it failed.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int pid;
    if ((pid = fork()) != 0)
    {
        // read in from stdin and pass to pipe
        // Need to test for fork() error here too
    }
    else
    {
        // read from pipe
        // write to out.txt
        // everything up to here works fine

        char *para[] = { "/bin/less", "Desktop/out.txt", 0 };
        execv(para[0], para);
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to execute %s\n", para[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Or:

```
        char *para[] = { "less", "Desktop/out.txt", 0 };
        execvp(para[0], para);
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to execute %s\n", para[0]);
```

The remarks in the code about pipes are puzzling since there is no sign of pipes other than in the comments.  As it stands, `less` will read the file it is told to read.  Note that `less` will not paginate its output if the output is not going to a terminal.  Since we can see no I/O redirection, we have to assume, then, that `less` will ignore anything the program tries to write to it, and will not send any data back to the program.

Comment: ok, i tried 'char *para[] = { "/usr/bin/less", "Desktop/out.txt", 0 }; execv(para[0],para); printf("error");' .The error msg wasn't come out and I have tested the data read from pipe is good. I can assume the execv() worked right? And how do redirect the less output to console? all I know about less is type in terminal "$ less somefile".....

Comment: Your example only shows your program trying to run `less Desktop/out.txt`.  There was no I/O redirection in your code, so it will read from the file and your keyboard, and it will write to the screen (console).  Create yourself the named file, and you should see that.  You might want to add `#include <sys/wait.h>` to the headers and `wait(0);` in the `if` clause.  You mention pipes; your code does not show pipes.  I'm not clear if you are trying to write to `less` or read from `less`, for example.  (I know which I think it should be, but that doesn't mean much.)  Maybe you need a new question?

Answer (score 1):

```
char* para[]={"less","/Desktop/out.txt"};
execv("/bin/less",para);
```

How does execv know when to stop reading parameters?

I think if you'd put code in there to handle execv() returning an error you'd have found this. You're also not testing for errors from fork().